# Spring JDBC Stored Procedure call timing out

Tags: spring

I am using Spring SimpleJBDCTemplate for a DB2 stored procedure call, the stored procedure returns around 200k records and it's kind of timing out from my java code.

I tried setMaxRecords option, it helps to an extent.

Is there something like a batch read or a page read that are part of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a library that is called Spring Batch. You should definitley see documentation and try to adapt it to your problem.

Please refer to this: [Spring-Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StoredProcedureItemReader)